# Unreadable text when converting .SHP to .CSV

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, csv, ogr2ogr

I am trying to convert .SHP file to .CSV using ogr2ogr in QGIS and I also have all the associated files related to the .SHP files. The text in the .SHP file is in Ukrainian and after the conversion, the text in the .CSV file is unreadable, aka it looks gibberish with random characters except for the fields that are composed of numbers. What can be done to resolve the issue?

My code is as follows (I have removed the actual folder paths for the purpose of this question):

```
import subprocess
import os
import io

ogr2ogr_path = r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.8\bin\ogr2ogr.exe'
input_folder = r'input folder path'
output_folder = r'output folder path'

os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if filename.endswith('.shp'):
        input_shapefile = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
        print(input_shapefile)
        output_csv = os.path.join(output_folder, f'{os.path.splitext(filename)[0]}.csv')
        print(output_csv)
        with io.open(output_csv, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as utf8_csv_file:
            result = subprocess.run([ogr2ogr_path, '-f', 'CSV', '/vsistdout/', input_shapefile], capture_output=True, text=True)
            if result.returncode == 0:
                utf8_csv_file.write(result.stdout)
                print(f"Converted: {filename}")
            else:
                print(f"Conversion failed for {filename}. Error: {result.stderr}")

print("Conversion completed successfully.")
```

Comment: Is the codepage used in the dBase file specified anywhere? If it's not UTF-8, reading it as if it were won't work.

Comment: You can check the encoding either in the .cpg file if it exists (if there are none I would guess it uses your os encoding ex: windows -> cp1252 if I remember correctly) or in the "Layer Properties" of the layer in QGIS under "Information from provider"

Comment: As it turns out, the encoding is windows-1251. I have replaced the UTF-8 to windows 1251, however the output file still remains unreadable.

Comment: Have you tried writing directly to the CSV file instead of to stdout, capturing the output and writing it manually? You could also look into the subprocess output encoding.